# How to compile production apk with minifyEnable and test apk with minifyEnable false?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I want to compile the debug production apk with minifyEnable true,
But after config it, the test apk has no test method, because all the methods are removed by proguard.

Keeping the method in proguard.flag (with testProguardFile) takes no effect.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks!

ps:
I use gradle 2.2.1, and android gradle plugin 1.1.0

I found some resource about this problem, but without success.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159831

Answer (score 0):

Minification can be enabled per build type. Simply omit `minifyEnabled` for build types where you don't want it (it is disabled by default), and add it to build types where you do:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        ...
    }
}
```

See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types